How to generate a 3d mesh from a 2d mask image
I have trained a segmentation model to detect walls from an image of a floorplan. Now, I wish to create a 3D mesh from the obtained masked array. I also need a mesh format that is compatible with a web viewer.
Below is the code that I used to extract the walls in my 2D image and some sample images.
This is the Masked Generated with AI:

These are the walls:

I imagine the next step is to create the 3D model out of it by extruding the footprint of the walls to a given height. How can I do that?
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
wall_height = 150
img_path = 'output_mask.png'

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Get the original dimensions of the image
original_height, original_width = img.shape[:2]

# Resize the image while preserving aspect ratio
new_width = 1024
new_height = int((new_width / original_width) * original_height)
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (new_width, new_height))

# Create a blank mask for the walls
walls = np.zeros(img_resized.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

# Extract the walls (walls are white in the image)
walls[(img_resized == [255, 255, 255]).all(axis=2)] = 255


Are there any constraints on your walls? i.e., are they always aligned with your x and y axis? Do they need to be "rectangular" or do you want to display their "imperfections" (e.g., thickness isn't always constant)? Depending on the answers, one possibility is to detect lines in your image using the Hough Transform https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html and make these lines you mesh edges (and their intersection your mesh vertices).

as you can see I store the walls mask in numpy array, for now I  am not worried about the imperfections. I just want to extrude the walls to a specific height for for 3d representation of these walls.

One solution would be to:

Detect lines in your second image using either the Hough Transform, RANSAC or any other suitable technique.
Check for the intersections of these lines in the 2D/image space. These are your 3D mesh vertices (with z coordinates = 0). The lines connecting these vertices are edges.
Create new vertices by using the x and y coordinates of the previous vertices and replacing z by your walls height (z_height).
Connect these vertices to the others: vertices with the same x and y coordinates (but z=0 and z=z_height) share an edge and the edges in the z=0 plane are the same than in the z=z_height plane.
Create quad faces from the edges (or break them into tri faces if needed). Be careful that the vertices/edges order must stay consistent (usually counter-clockwise).
Save the result in a file, in whatever format you want: STL, OBJ, OFF, etc.


can you help me code it?

I am a total beginner in python and 3d which is why I don't have a understanding on how to implement it...

Making a program that converts 2D floorplans to 3D models is basically an active research topic (if you're not convinced just check it on Google Scholar). While your problem seems to be more simple/specific, it would still require days/weeks of development in my opinion. My advice is that you take this opportunity to learn about Python, image processing and machine learning. You can break you problem into smaller ones and then try to "glue all together". Look for tutorials and for Github repo that cover this subject. Good luck!

remember, SO isn't a code writing service. leave the asker some parts to do themselves.

I tried with a python library meshlib and it did generate the 3d models but the next step is I want to place some furniture 3d models in specific places, I will detect the furniture from a trained model and mark them on the mask just like these walls then I want to place the 3d furniture at that marks. I think it won't be possible with meshlib
